# Check if delete was caused by CASCADE DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, cascade

I've been searching all over but can't find an answer to this.  Is there a way for a delete trigger to detect if the delete was caused by a DELETE statement or through a CASCADE DELETE on the Parent Table?

I have Table A which has a PK and Table B which as FK on Table A with ON DELETE CASCADE.

I want to create a Delete Trigger on Table B that checks if the delete was caused by a record in Table A being deleted and allow the delete to take place but prevent the Delete if it was a DELETE Statement on Table B.

The only work around I've come up with so far is a Delete Trigger on Table A that Disables the Delete Trigger on Table B, Deletes the record in Table B and then Enables the Trigger on Table B again but this doesn't feel like an Elegant Solution.

Thanks for any input :)

Comment: one more work around would be to create a dummy log table/ Global variable or something like that which logs delete on your parent table, and in delete trigger of child table, check the same log table. Based on your filled values, you should be able to check if the delete was caused by cascade or not

Comment: Thanks for the input Codeek, that definitely makes sense though it would probably then be more robust to rather use a trigger on table A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the Trigger option as it looks to be the most elegant solution and doesn't look too bad after I actually scripted it out.  Here's the script if it helps someone else or anyone wants to comment on it:

```
/* 
Create the MAILBOXES CRPREDEL1 Trigger 
Creates the Trigger which Deletes all Folders ( and by Cascade all Files ) when a Mailbox gets Deleted
*/
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CRPREDEL1_MBX]
ON [dbo].[MAILBOXES]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
    DECLARE @SqlIdentity        int

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE c_primary CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT d.MBX_SQLIDENTITY
                                           FROM deleted d
        BEGIN
            OPEN c_primary
            FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @SqlIdentity
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                -- Disable CRPOSDEL1_MFO so we can delete System Folders
                ALTER TABLE [MAILBOX_FOLDERS] DISABLE TRIGGER [CRPOSDEL1_MFO]

                -- Delete the Mailbox Folders
                DELETE FROM [MAILBOX_FOLDERS] WHERE [MFO_MAILBOX] = @SqlIdentity

                -- Enable CRPOSDEL1_MFO so System Folders can't be deleted anymore
                ALTER TABLE [MAILBOX_FOLDERS] ENABLE TRIGGER [CRPOSDEL1_MFO]

                -- Delete the Actual Mailbox now
                DELETE FROM [MAILBOXES] WHERE [MBX_SQLIDENTITY] = @SqlIdentity  

                FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @SqlIdentity
            END
            CLOSE c_primary
        END
        DEALLOCATE c_primary
    END
GO
```

Thanks for the input guys, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know (or can determine) the foreign key constraint(s) involved, you can look at the      DELETE_RULE column from DBA_CONSTRAINTS

```
SELECT constraint_name, delete_rule
FROM dba_constraints
WHERE r_constraint_name = <<name of the primary key constraint>>
AND r_owner = <<owner of the primary key constraint>>
AND delete_rule = 'CASCADE'
```

Comment: Hi Sandipon, thanks for the feedback. I'm not familiar with dba_constraints, is that an Oracle table? I'm using MS SQL Server, my apologies, I thought the sql-server tag would have marked that but I'll be sure to add it in the actual body next time.